# How to change video url for MPMoviePlayerViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am developing for iOS 6 using Xcode 4.6.1 (Target is iPad)

I am trying to change the video URL when the user swipes the screen.

This is my `ViewController.m` file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface experiencesViewController () {
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerViewController;
    MPMoviePlayerController *player;
}

@end

...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:"video" ofType:@"mp4"];

    playerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];

    player = [playerViewController moviePlayer];
    [player setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];
    player.fullscreen = YES;

    [player play];

    ...

}

...
```

Now, I want to change the video on a swipe event. I tried doing this:

```
- (IBAction)didSwipeLeft:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"Left");

    player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    player.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"video2.mp4"];

    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player play];
}
```

However, this doesn't work. The video stops playing and nothing happens after that. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you not just create a new movie player, pop the old one and push a new one?

Comment: Well, that is one option, but I was wondering if there was a way to simply update the URL and play the next video.

Answer (score 0):

remove the [player play] because the video is not yet ready to play.

Comment: I tried doing that, but there's no difference. The video stops playing.

Comment: player.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"video2.mp4"]; sounds like this is not a valid url -

Comment: The URL is fine. I double checked it. I tried putting `video2.mp4` instead of `video.mp4` in `viewDidLoad` and it works. So I guess it isn't a URL issue.

Comment: NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:"video2" ofType:@"mp4"]; player.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url]; try! and never give up!

Comment: did you get any solution?